# bash: read multi-line string into multiple variables

Tags: string, bash

How can I assign a newline-separated string with e.g. three lines to three variables ?

```
# test string
s='line 01
line 02
line 03'

# this doesn't seem to make any difference at all
IFS=$'\n'

# first naive attempt
read a b c <<< "${s}"

# this prints 'line 01||':
# everything after the first newline is dropped
echo "${a}|${b}|${c}"

# second attempt, remove quotes
read a b c <<< ${s}

# this prints 'line 01 line 02 line 03||':
# everything is assigned to the first variable
echo "${a}|${b}|${c}"

# third attempt, add -r
read -r a b c <<< ${s}

# this prints 'line 01 line 02 line 03||':
# -r switch doesn't seem to make a difference
echo "${a}|${b}|${c}"

# fourth attempt, re-add quotes
read -r a b c <<< "${s}"

# this prints 'line 01||':
# -r switch doesn't seem to make a difference
echo "${a}|${b}|${c}"
```

I also tried using `echo ${s} | read a b c` instead of `<<<`, but couldn't get that to work either.

Can this be done in bash at all ?

Comment: You might want to consider `mapfile` or `readarray` and use arrays instead of differently named variables for something like this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

read default input delimiter is \n

```
{ read a; read b; read c;} <<< "${s}"
```

-d char : allows to specify another input delimiter

For example is there is no character SOH (1 ASCII) in input string

```
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d$'\1' a b c <<< "${s}"
```

We set `IFS` to `$'\n'` because IFS default value is :

```
$ printf "$IFS" | hd -c
00000000  20 09 0a                                          | ..|
0000000      \t  \n                                                    
0000003
```

EDIT: -d can take a null argument the space is mandatory between -d and null argument:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' a b c <<< "${s}"
```

The `read` builtin documentation is available by typing `help read` at the bash prompt.

EDIT: after comment about a solution for any number of lines

```
function read_n {
    local i s n line
    n=$1
    s=$2
    arr=()
    for ((i=0;i<n;i+=1)); do
        IFS= read -r line
        arr[i]=$line
    done <<< "${s}"
}

nl=$'\n'
read_n 10 "a${nl}b${nl}c${nl}d${nl}e${nl}f${nl}g${nl}h${nl}i${nl}j${nl}k${nl}l"

printf "'%s'\n" "${arr[@]}"
```

Another way without using `read`

```
IFS=$'\n'   # avoid space/tab splitting
set -f      # avoid file globbing
arr=($s)
# possibly restore defaults
IFS=$' \t\n'
set +f
```

Comment: This seems to be the only way to get this going. Not very elegant and does not scale nicely, but at least it works.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by not elegant and does not scale, isn't that the answer to your question

Comment: You are correct that this answers my question; however, the three lines in my question only served as an example, my actual use case has more lines and called `read` e.g. 10 times for 10 lines does not seem very elegant to me - a solution where the same code works for any number of lines would scale better.

Answer (score 8):

You are looking for the `readarray` command, not `read`.

```
readarray -t lines <<< "$s"
```

(Theoretically, `$s` does not need to be quoted here. Unless you are using `bash` 4.4 or later, I would quote it anyway, due to some bugs in previous versions of `bash`.)

Once the lines are in an array, you can assign the separate variables if you need to

```
a=${lines[0]}
b=${lines[1]}
c=${lines[2]}
```

Comment: This would be the preferable approach, but it unfortunately only works on Linux, not on macOS as `readarray` (aka `mapfile`) is only available in Bash 4 on the former, but not the latter.

Comment: One can easily install a recent version of `bash` on OS X. The system `bash` should basically be considered an implementation of POSIX shell.

Comment: I am using `GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0)` installed on OS X 10.11.6 using homebrew. Recent enough.

Comment: This is my preferred solution.