# How to read multi-line properties from text files in bash with grep

Tags: bash, grep, sh, git-bash

I want to read properties from a build file using `grep 3.1` in bash (gitbash, actually). Most properties in the file have single line value, some have no value while others like `REFLIBS` contains multiline value.

```
REFLIBS=module.o testModule1.o libutil.a \
                               libdebug.a \
                               libxfor.a
SOURCEFILES=client.c
FLAGS=
HEADERS=linkedlist.h
#OLD_REFLIBS  ignore lines with bash-style comments
#HEADERS=utils.h
```

**Problem**

My grep command:
`grep -i -m 1 -E '^REFLIBS=' test.txt`

The command captures only up to the first `\`, but my goal is to concatenate all lines into a single line like this:

```
REFLIBS_CAPTURE=$(grep -i -m 1 -E '^REFLIBS=' test.txt)
echo $REFLIBS_CAPTURE
(desired output)
> module.o testModule1.o libutil.a libdebug.a libxfor.a
```

Before posting I searched again and found this post suggesting to alter default IFS input delimiter from `'\n'` to something else, in my case `\`. Looks interesting but not sure if this is the right solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44112055/791406

Comment: Would pre-processing the file to remove (or replace with a space) all instances of a backslash followed by a newline work? Then you would only need to match the single line.

Comment: Did not think of that. It will be slower for sure as I'm reading ~ 4000 files, so creating a new file then reading it will slow things down but at this point I'll try anything.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to provide sample input that you want to print that 3-line block from, otherwise we really don't have anything to test a potential solution against. Make sure to include similar-looking blocks that you do NOT want printed as it's usually easy to print strings you want to match but much harder to not print similar strings you do not want to match,

Comment: @EdMorton Updated with more details and desired output.

Comment: If you are worried about performance, I would not create a separate child process (`grep`), or even two child processes (as in the answer you have accepted) for **each** property you want to extract, but parse the whole file **once** and store all the properties into an associative array in bash. After this, you can retrieve them quickly from the array. I would do this parsing just with bash internal commands, without and child processes.

Comment: @user1934428 using just bash commands would require a loop reading lines which would be extremely slow, relatively lengthy, and hard to write robustly, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: @EdMorton: Still much faster than creating a child process for each key to extract. Unless the property file is extremly large, this should not be a problem. Also, the file structure looks pretty simple, and I don't think that it difficult to find a robust solution, even in bash.

Comment: @user1934428 Yes but orders of magnitude slower than, more code than, and more complicated code than, just calling awk to parse the file once. A shell is a tool to create/destroy files and processes and sequence calls to tools, not a tool to manipulate text - the people who invented shell also invented awk for shell to call to manipulate text.

Comment: @EdMorton : `awk` (or Perl or Ruby ....) would make parsing more efficient, but then you have to somehow transport back the result into the bash shell, where the OP wants to use the properties. One possibility would be to generate from the parser an output file or output string, which is then sourced or eval'ed, and we have then to care about generating parsable bash code. IMHO from the viewpoint of maintenance a nightmare. I would start with a quick parser in bash, filling up an assoc array, and only if I find that it's to slow, then think about a different approach.

Comment: @user1934428 Populating a bash array from a tool output is trivial (**IF** the OP really needed that instead of just doing whatever they need in awk), I definitely would not source or eval anything, it would not be any kind of maintenance problem, and you would not experience a performance issue and so wouldn't potentially have to rewrite your code if/when your input grew or your tool had to be called in a loop.

Comment: @EdMorton: I disagree here. Populating an associative array from the command output is [not that simple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39417793/how-do-i-populate-a-bash-associative-array-with-command-output), since the values can contain spaces and you have to generate the quoting needed for preserving the white space, and then you have to escape the quotes too, if quotes are part of the value.

Comment: @user1934428 as you'll see in the answer to that question, I was just missing quotes (a common shell gotcha). If you wouldn't mind posting a question about how to populate a bash array from some lines from an input file, I think it'd be good to show solutions using both approaches.

Comment: I fear that such a question would be closed as duplicate, as there are several discussions on stackoverflow how to populate an assoc array from an external program. I could try to sketch my suggested approach as an answer here. Note that your answer is of course best to pick one specific property for a file, but if you need several properties, you have to create an awk process for each property.

Comment: @user1934428 you would not create an awk process for each property, you'd pass awk a list of property names when you call it once. If you did come up with a lengthier input file in the same style of the OPs (i.e. tag=value pairs where the values can contain escaped newlines) and post an answer that extracts multiple properties from it and does something we need shell for with it, e.g. calling `md5sum` on each value before printing the result, I'd be willing to add a solution for that to my current answer. Please do include any cases you think will be difficult for the awk->shell array case.

Comment: @EdMorton : I see. Still I have posted my answer for comparision, which IMO is also more flexible: I don't need to decide in advance, which properties are required, and I can for instance easily get a list of all properties, if needed.

Comment: @user1934428 I fixed a couple of obvious issues in your code but it still doesn't print the values of any properties. The devil is always in the details with a shell script (an idea usually requires a lot more code than expected to get to a robust implementation!). If you get your code working then I'll update my answer to provide an awk answer that does the same. I disagree that the shell code will be more flexibe, you wouldn't need to decide anything in advance with an awk script either, and it can also easily get a list of all properties if needed.

Comment: @EdMorton : I indeed had a typo in a variable name, which I fixed. Moreover, you helped me to an idea how to considerably simplify the program, and I posted the simplified version to, together with an explanation. If you can think of a testcase, where my program would fail, please let me know.

Comment: @raffian I see you added a line that starts with a `#` and said "ignore lines with bash-style comments". That's clear enough for lines that **start** with a `#` but what about cases where the `#` appears mid-line? Please [edit] your question to add the input and expected output for these cases `FOO=this    # as a comment` and `BAR="this # in a string"` and `ETC='this # also in a string'` if such entries can appear in your input.

Comment: @raffian : Adding to the valid remark by EdMorton: How would then a property be defined, which has a comment inside its value (so that you can distinguish it from the start of a comment)? I see the main problem with your question that you never define the format of the property file; just giving examples is not enough, because we need then to guess what you mean.

Comment: @EdMorton My apologies for not being clear on "bash-style comments", if a line starts with `#`, it's a comment and should be ignored. If `#` appears anywhere else it's part of the line, not a comment.

Comment: Technically wpeaking, `REFLIBS` also has only a **single** value, although there are spaces in this value. To define it as a variable containing several values, you would have to defint it as array.

Comment: I think in order to provide a good answer, you would have to define first the syntax of your _property file_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed` to delete each backlash-newline sequence, and then match only a single line with grep:

```
sed -z 's/\\\n *//g' < test.txt | grep -i -m 1 -E '^REFLIBS='
```

which outputs

```
REFLIBS=module.o testModule1.o libutil.a libdebug.a libxfor.a
```

Note that GNU `sed` is required for the `-z` option, which treats lines as being NUL-separated instead of newline separated. The means that you effectively read the entire input file into memory as a single "line" for `sed` to operate on.

Comment: This worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you want, using any awk:

```
$ awk '/^REFLIBS=/{f=1} f; !/\\$/{f=0}' file
REFLIBS=module.o testModule1.o libutil.a \
                               libdebug.a \
                               libxfor.a
```

or to implement all of your `grep` options (`-i` for case-insensitive comparison and `-m 1` to exit after first match, `-E` is doing nothing) would be:

```
awk 'toupper($0) ~ /^REFLIBS=/{f=1} f{print; if (!/\\$/) exit}' file
```

or if you have a blank line between each variable setting then all you need is:

```
awk -v RS= '/^REFLIBS=/'
```

etc...

Answer (score 1):

I would not turn property names blindly into bash variable names, since they may clash with variables which are already set, or variables which have a specific meaning to bash. Instead I would load all properties of the file into a single array and access them via the array.

The following code is a sketch of the algorithm. I did **not** test it, but by and large, the idea should be clear. It assumes that the properties are in a file `property_file.txt` and will be loaded into an array `prop`:

```
declare -A prop # Array of properties
in_continuation=0 # Are we currently processing continuation lines?
while read -r
do
  if [[ $REPLY == '#'* || -z $REPLY ]]
  then
    : comment or empty line
  else
    if [[ $REPLY == *\\ ]]
    then
      # line ends in \
      if ((in_continuation==0))
      then
        # start a new continuation
        in_continuation=1
        continuation=''
      fi
       continuation+=$REPLY
    else
      # line does not end in \
      if ((in_continuation==1))
      then
        # continuation ends here
        line=$continuation$REPLY
        in_continuation=0
      else
        line=$REPLY
      fi
      # Process $line
      if [[ $line =~ ^([^=]*)=(.*) ]]
      then
        property_name=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        property_value=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        prop[$property_name]=$property_value
      else
        echo "Illegal property line '$line'" 1>&2
      fi
    fi
  fi            
done <property_file.txt

echo "The property REFLIBS has the value ${prop[REFLIBS]}"
echo "The property PATH has the value ${prop[PATH]}"
echo "The property FOO has the value ${prop[FOO]}"
```

**UPDATE** I fixed a typo, and the missing handling of empty lines, and now it should work correctly.

Furthermore, I found that I don't need to handle continuation lines on my own. The `read` command by itself (unless this feature is turned off via the `-r` flag) is clever enough to treat lines ending in a backslash as continuation lines. With this in mind, the program simplifies to

```
declare -A prop # Array of properties
while read
do
  if [[ $REPLY == '#'* || -z $REPLY ]]
  then
    : comment or empty line
  elif [[ $REPLY =~ ^([^=]*)=(.*) ]]
  then
    property_name=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    property_value=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    prop[$property_name]=$property_value
  else
    echo "Illegal property line '$line'"
  fi
done <property_file.txt
```

I tested both versions against a property file having the content

```
REFLIBS= a b\
 c
###comment
PATH=xx
FOO='this=that'
```

and it produced the desired output.

Comment: I tried this but both echoes returned blank values.

Comment: @raffian : Try it now with the updated code. Use my example data first to verify that it works on your platform. Also, what bash version do you use? I'm running 5.2.15.

Comment: By removing the `-r` I had previously added to your `read` you're telling `read` to interpret escape sequences so, for example, `REFLIBS=watch\this\now` in the input would become `REFLIBS=watch<literal tab>his<literal newline>ow` when stored in the array and in the output.

Comment: It'd also cause lines to be joined without a space so `PATH=a b\<literal newline>c` from the input would become `PATH=a bc` instead of the presumably desirable `PATH=a b c` in the array+output. The OP provided sample input, btw, you could just use that as a starting point to test the script rather than coming up with your own.

Comment: FYI I'm only looking at your first script as the second one relaying on removing `-r` can't work reliably so - You asked me to think of cases it wouldn't work for: try it with `FOO='this=that'`. The line `$line =~ ^(.*)=(.*)` needs to be `$line =~ ^([^=[:space:]]*)[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*(.*)` or similar.

Comment: @EdMorton: The "missing" space is on purpose. This is the very idea to continuation lines. bash handles them the same. The main oddity in the example provided by the OP is that he seems to squeeze multiple space into a single space. I don't think he really means this (he does not mention it explicitly), but if this is desired, he can easily modify my algorithm to perfom this space compression as well.

Comment: @EdMorton : Thanks for the example. I fixed the bug in my regex, in a slightly different way from your suggestion.

Comment: @EdMorton : I also tested it with the original data from the OP, and the result looks reasonable to me.

Comment: Regarding the "missing" space - that's fair. I was thinking that people don't usually put an escaped line-break mid-word BUT no reason to guess at what they meant when they can always put a space at the start of a line if it's what they wanted.

Comment: @EdMorton : I found both scripts working now. According to my bash man-page, the purpose of `-r` is to **not** interpret a backslash as last character as a continuation character. Since in my second solution, I **want** `read` to handle continuation lines automaticallly, I dropped the `-r`.

Comment: `-r` is "raw" mode to treat lines as-is. You remove it to ask bash to interpret/transform the input including by converting escape sequences. e.g. to convert `\n` to newline, `\t` to tab, etc. Try your script with input like `PATH='this\that\now'` (imagine that's a WIndows path, for a real example) with and without the `-r`.

Comment: I was wrong about `\t`->tab, etc. (guess my memory is going!), it just stripped the ```\```s. Still a problem though.

Comment: @EdMorton : You are right indeed. Depending on what the OP really wants, we can regard this as feature or not. I think it is good that I kept both versions of my program, i.e. including the one where I handle line continuations by myself.

Comment: FYI (again, just because you asked me to let you know of failure cases) when I put a line like ```THIS=that \``` between ```PATH= a b\``` and ```c``` it outputs PATH as empty instead of `a b THIS=that c`. It'd also print it as empty if ```PATH=a b\``` appeared at the end of the file. I'm not sure it's worth continuing with this since the OP already accepted an answer ....

Comment: @user1934428  Yes, it's working now, nice alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're working against bash, not with it. Why do you want to parse bash syntax when you have bash right there?

Source the build file:

```
. test.txt
```

Now all your variables are in bash.

For most people, that will be enough. But if you want to do something weird and wonderful, start a fresh bash with a clean environment (env -i bash), and let that sub-shell bash do whatever it is you want done.

Comment: Certainly most efficient, but dangerous due to possible code injection. I think the reason why the OP wanted to parse the property file, is because he does not want to take any risk. Also think about the case where a property file defines a property named, say, `PATH` or `HOME`.

Comment: @user1934428 he said it's a build file, and if you can't trust your own build files, who can you trust? Too many people go down the rabbit hole of code injection, when that's just not the scenario at hand. And if you for some ridiculous reason want to do this in a public facing web site, good bloody luck convincing yourself that all your pattern matching and awk and quoting is up to snuff. Nothing remotely bash based should be anywhere near anything public facing.

Comment: I would trust maybe the **specification** of the build file, which we don't know. But imagine that the build file is specified as simple `NAME=VALUE` pairs, without having bash in mind, and that an entry `X=*` is **intended** to set the name X to a single asterisk as value. Sourcing the file would cause expansion here. If however the build file **is** specified to be "bash code", then of course we would source it; but I would not call it _build file_, but _build script_. It's then jut another program in your project.

Comment: @user1934428   FOO=* ; echo "$FOO"  =>  *   no expansion.

Comment: Correct. My example should be something like `X=(*)`. In this case, `echo "$X"`would **not** show `(*)`.

Comment: I don't know why you'd have a bash config file and not have bash in mind. After all, if you don't know what you're dealing with you'd be left wondering how it treats spaces, how you insert special characters etc etc. Any other solution you're going to have to come to terms with that.

Comment: This is a quite valid idea: The OP mentions  bash, and he mentions _a property file_, but he never mentions the syntax of the property file. Of course, if the property file were simply a bash script, this would be trivial; but the sheer fact that the OP never mentions this relationship of his property file or bash, makes me suspect that the property file is **not** supposed to be bash syntax. It could (just for instance) also be a Java property file ... IMO, the question should be closed, because it is too unprecise.